Unable to receive the data on client side of udp protocol on codesys
I try to send and receive data using a UDP connection via SysSocket 3.5.17.0. While sending data works fine, I have problems with the receiving part.I am able to capture the data of client side in wireshark but i am unable to capture it in the codesys. Heres the below part of code of client side.
3:
//receive data
xiRecBytes := syssocket.SysSockRecvFrom(iecSocketId,ADR(sDataRec),SIZEOF(sDataRec),0,ADR(ipAddr),SIZEOF(ipAddr),ADR(iecRecResult));
istep := 4;

I tried to capture the data of client side in wireshark it was capturing but unable to receive it in the codesys software.
